# NodeJS Data is shared between API Calls issue

Tags: node.js

We are running nodejs which will fetch a data based on list of IDs (for example 123, 124, 125, 126) as post call

```
www.mydomain.com/fetchnodejsAPI  -input format: {id:123,124,125,126}
```

We are taking the requestid and assigning to

```
const context={}; context.id=req.id;
```

Now the issue is when I call from spring batch process with more than 10 threads, data between requests are shared.

We have the function written as async all the way down expect for the actual function which is doing the querying from DB.

How can i avoid this?
Is there way to make sure even when we are calling the API concurrently form external program, we should not send the wrong data.

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. when multiple calls issued from external program and we use promise(resolve,reject) which is waiting for a connection form DB, by the time it gets a connection already 4 calls in queue and the  local variable in scope (sql query) overwritten with last value and tahts why we have problem

solution is to not use a local variable and pass it as parameter to the function.